# Displaying data from multiple queries in a single pie chart using cfchart tag

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following code, right now I have the following code in my `.cfm` page inside the `<body>` tag:

```
DataSource = xx.xx.x.xx
Name of the database = sgemail
Name of the relevant column = event_vc
```

Basically I have calculated the percentage of the open connections in the following queries.

```
<cfquery datasource = "xx.xx.x.xx" name="qSen">

SELECT (select count(*) 
        FROM sgemail) AS TOTAL_CONNECTIONS,
        (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM sgemail 
        WHERE event_vc = "open") AS OPEN_CONNECTIONS,
        (ROUND((SELECT OPEN_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "% OPEN" ;
</cfquery>


<cfquery datasource = "xx.xx.x.xx" name="qSen">

SELECT (select count(*) from sgemail) AS TOTAL_CONNECTIONS,
(SELECT count(*) from sgemail where event_vc = "BOUNCE") AS BOUNCE_CONNECTIONS,
(ROUND((SELECT BOUNCE_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "% BOUNCE" ;
</cfquery>
```

Basically `"% OPEN"` and `"% BOUNCE" are used to display the percentage of connections open and bounce from the database.

I have included the following `<cfchart>` tag below the above `<cfquery>` tag as follows:

```
<cfchart
         format="png"
         scalefrom="0"
         scaleto="1200000"
         pieslicestyle="solid">

         <cfchartseries
          type="pie"
          serieslabel="Website Traffic 2006"
          seriescolor="blue"
          query = "qSengrid"
          valuecolumn="% OPEN"

          itemcolumn=""
          >

    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

My Questions:

1) The thing is that the above chart is displaying only one circle with yellow color. I want to display the information retrieved by both the queries in one chart. For example
the value I'm getting for `%OPEN` is 30 and value I'm getting for `%Bounce` is 20. I have other queries as well which return different values which makes the whole pie chart 
to 100 but I have included only two cfqueries for the sake of simplicity for this question. Please let me know how to proceed further.

2) Also, when I commented out the second query (where I'm getting `% Bounce` value), I can see the value of `%OPEN` next to the circle of the pie-chart. However, when I run both
the queries with only one `<cfchart>` mentioned above (with `valuecolumn = %OPEN` ) I can't see any value written next to the circle.

Please answer my above questions and let me know if there are any questions I can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments)

By using reusing the same query name, you are most likely overwriting the previous results. In addition, that is not how `<cfchartseries query="...">` works. It accepts a *single* query, which means all of the values must be contained in the same query.

If you must use separate queries, give each query a unique name and a use separate `<cfchartdata>` tag for *each* value:

```
<cfchart format="png">
    <cfchartseries type="pie">
         <cfchartdata item="% Open" value="#qTotalOpen.TotalNumber#">
         <cfchartdata item="% Bounce" value="#qTotalBounced.TotalNumber#">
         ... other values ...
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

Comment: Awesome man ! It worked. So there is no need of query item in chartdata item. I was trying to figure out that only for each charts and how to keep it in one.

Comment: Right. `cfchartdata` is designed to let you construct a chart manually. So only a "value" and "label" are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ColdFusion, but it looks like the issue is getting the `% Open` and `% Bounce` values into the same result set. Based on your markup examples, I think your result needs to look something like this (I made up the column names):

```
theitem   thevalue
--------- --------
% OPEN          40
% BOUNCE        23
```

Then your markup in `<cfcchart>` would go something like this:

```
<cfchartseries
      type="pie"
      serieslabel="Website Traffic 2006"
      seriescolor="blue"
      query = "qSengrid"
      valuecolumn="thevalue"
      itemcolumn="theitem"
>
```

If that's the case (and remember I'm guessing here because nobody else has posted an answer yet), then the accompanying query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('% ', UPPER(sgemail.event_vc)) AS theitem,
  COUNT(*) / tots.totconn AS thevalue
FROM
  sgemail,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totconn
   FROM sgemail
   WHERE event_vc IN ('open', 'bounce')) tots
WHERE tots.totconn <> 0
  AND sgemail.event_vc IN ('open', 'bounce')
GROUP BY CONCAT('% ', UPPER(sgemail.event_vc))
```

The query is a bit involved because it's calculating percentages for a subset of `event_vc` values, plus it's guarding against a divide by zero error. If the chart can take straight counts and convert them to percentages, the query for "counts only" is a lot simpler:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('% ', UPPER(sgemail.event_vc)) AS theitem,
  COUNT(*) / tots.totconn AS thevalue
FROM sgemail
WHERE sgemail.event_vc IN ('open', 'bounce')
GROUP BY CONCAT('% ', UPPER(sgemail.event_vc))
```