# Playing around with date range in ColdFusion 8

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following code:

In this code, a user will be asked to select a date range from the two options and click on apply button so that the result can be displayed on the web browser for the selected date range.
I'm wondering how should I proceed. Please throw some light on this.

2) How can I make sure that I can enable the option of downloading the data using "Download CSV" option?

Please let me know what changes are required. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body>

<cfparam name="Form.startdate" default="#dateformat(now()-5, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="Form.enddate" default="#dateformat(now()-1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="Form.selectdate" default="#dateformat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">


<!--- <cfquery datasource = "xx.xx.x.x" name="qCheck">

SELECT * 
FROM   mydatabase
ORDER BY DTSId_bi LIMIT 10;

</cfquery>
 --->

<cfquery datasource = "xx.xx.x.x" name="qDatabase">

SELECT    (SELECT count(*) FROM mydatabase) AS TOTAL_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*)FROM mydatabase WHERE event_vc = "open") AS OPEN_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*)FROM mydatabase WHERE event_vc = "BOUNCE") AS BOUNCE_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*) from mydatabase where event_vc = "DEFERRED") AS DEFERRED_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*) from mydatabase where event_vc = "DELIVERED") AS DELIVERED_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*) from mydatabase where event_vc = "DROPPED") AS DROPPED_CONNECTIONS,
          (SELECT count(*) from mydatabase where event_vc = "PROCESSED") AS PROCESSED_CONNECTIONS,
          (ROUND((SELECT OPEN_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "OPEN",
          (ROUND((SELECT BOUNCE_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "BOUNCE" ,
          (ROUND((SELECT DEFERRED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DEFERRED",
          (ROUND((SELECT DELIVERED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DELIVERED",
          (ROUND((SELECT DROPPED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DROPPED",
          (ROUND((SELECT PROCESSED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "PROCESSED";
</cfquery>



<cfform format="flash" preloader ="false">

<!--- Arranging the two buttons adjacent to each other using cfformgroup tag --->
<cfformgroup type="horizontal">


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <cfinput type="dateField" name="startdate" label="Start Date" width="100" value="#Form.startdate#">
  <cfinput type="dateField" name="enddate" label="End Date" width="100" value="#Form.enddate#">
  <cfinput name="submit" type="submit" value = "Apply">
  <cfinput name="cancel" type="submit" value="Download CSV">
</p>
</cfformgroup>

<!--- For Horizontal Line --->
<cfformitem type = "hrule" style=""></cfformitem>


</cfform>

<cfchart
         format="png"
         chartwidth="500"
         chartheight="500"
         scalefrom="0"
         scaleto="1200000"
         title="Email Reporting "
         pieslicestyle="solid">

         <cfchartseries type="line"
                         >

        <cfchartdata item="% OPEN" value="#qDatabase.OPEN#">
        <cfchartdata item="% BOUNCE" value="#qDatabase.BOUNCE#">
        <cfchartdata item="% DEFERRED" value="#qDatabase.DEFERRED#">
        <cfchartdata item="% DELIVERED" value="#qDatabase.DELIVERED#">
        <cfchartdata item="% DROPPED" value="#qDatabase.DROPPED#">
        <cfchartdata item="% PROCESSED" value="#qDatabase.PROCESSED#"> 


    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>





</body>
```

Comment: There's just too damn much there that needs work.  Most of those stats could be done with `SELECT COUNT(*) , event_vc FROM mydatabase WHERE event_vc IN ('open','BOUNCE','DEFERRED','DELIVERED','DROPPED','PROCESSED')` instead of all those subqueries.  I'm amazed if that query even returns what you expect it to. That and you seem to basically be asking someone to write you a method to generate a CSV file for that data. At the end of the day, all you are needing to do is figure out how to generate the output string and output it to the browser with the correct headers.

Comment: Yeah, I think the code quality question ought to be on code review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here. And it does need work. That leaves the "how do I respond with CSV data rather than mark-up" is a separate question, and most of the text of this question is irrelevant. Suggest moving the code, and rewording the question.

Comment: Agreed, this should be two separate threads. The first: how to filter this query on a date range. The second: how to export to csv. [Your previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17411536/104223) provided a starting point for simplifying your query - something you definitely need to do before adding date filters. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Leigh My previous query worked fine. I used the same code which I mentioned in this thread.

Comment: @AaK - No I meant did you try [Ed's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17411536/104223)? He got rid of all those individual subqueries and replaced it with a JOIN. It will be *much* easier to add date filters to *his* query, than your current one with all those subqueries ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would really consider re-working the qDatabase query it is VERY inefficient!  As far as downloading a csv the best way is to write a file to a temp area that frequestly gets cleaned out so it doesn't fill up you HD.  I will help with writing the file but not the clean up lol.  You can do something like this:

```
<cfscript>
    var tl ='';
    var nl = (Chr( 13 ) & Chr( 10 ));
    var fileContent = createObject("java","java.lang.StringBuffer").init();
    var counter =1;
    fileContent.append( 'OPEN,BOUNCE,DEFERRED,DELIVERED, etc');
     fileContent.append(nl);
            for(i=1;i<=qDatabase.recordCount;i=i+1){
                tl = qDatabase.OPEN&','qDatabase.BOUNCE&','qDatabase.DEFERRED&','qDatabase.DELIVERED&',' etc;
                fileContent.append(tl);
                fileContent.append(nl);
            }

</cfscript>
<cffile action="write" file="#absoluteFilePathAndName#" mode="775" output="#fileContent.toString()#"/>
<a href="#realtiveFilePathAndName#>Download</a>
```

This will write a csv file to the absolute path every time someone hits the page so you will want some conditional logic around it to prevent that happening.

Over all you need to relook at the code you have provided and rethink what you are doing but once you do this code will get you started IT IS NOT your final solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll work on it and mention here if I encounter any problems.

Comment: If you find the correct headers to use you can also output directly to the browser + trigger a file download which would remove the step where you need to write to disk.  I think it's something like `<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/csv"><cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=yourFileNameHere.csv"><cfheader name="cache-control" value="nocache"><cfoutput>#fileContent#` (used in place of the `<cffile><a>....</a>` in @Lance's answer)

Comment: @Lance @ Simon at mso.net  Could you guys tell me from where I can read more about Chr(10), fileContent etc. I'm not familiar with the terminologies you have used and finding it difficult to understand. Thanks

Comment: You can look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_04.html and http://www.ascii-code.com/  `(Chr( 13 ) & Chr( 10 ))` is basically a carriage return and a line feed