# Date format and SQL Query clarification

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following piece of code ( In the context of my previous thread [Playing around with date range in ColdFusion 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559071/playing-around-with-date-range-in-coldfusion-8/17559434?noredirect=1#17559434)).

```
<cfparam name="Form.startdate" default="#dateformat(now()-5, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="Form.enddate" default="#dateformat(now()-1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="Form.selectdate" default="#dateformat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">


<cfinput type="dateField" name="startdate" label="Start Date" width="100" value="#Form.startdate#">
<cfinput type="dateField" name="enddate" label="End Date" width="100" value="#Form.enddate#">
<cfinput name="submit" type="submit" value = "Apply">
<cfinput name="cancel" type="submit" value="Download CSV">
```

I have following questions:

1) When the user will select a date(startdate) from the calender, is the date automatically going to pass to the "value" field of the following line?

```
 <cfinput type="dateField" name="startdate" label="Start Date" width="100" value="#Form.startdate#">
```

If the above is true then I believe the same thing will apply with the end date as well.

2) Regarding the SQL Query:

Suppose I'm writing the following query(Please note that "UpdatedDate" is the name of the column from where I'll be pulling up the "startdate" and
   "enddate":

```
             <cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="qMyDatabase">
            SELECT(SELECT count(*) FROM MyDatabase) AS TOTAL_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM MyDatabase WHERE event_vc = "OPEN" AND UpdatedDate BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#  ) AS OPEN_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*)FROM MyDatabase WHERE event_vc = "BOUNCE"    AND  UpdatedDate    BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#) AS BOUNCE_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*) from MyDatabase where event_vc = "DEFERRED" AND  UpdatedDate    BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#) AS DEFERRED_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*) from MyDatabase where event_vc = "DELIVERED" AND UpdatedDate    BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#) AS DELIVERED_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*) from MyDatabase where event_vc = "DROPPED"  AND  UpdatedDate    BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#) AS DROPPED_CONNECTIONS,
            (SELECT count(*) from MyDatabase where event_vc = "PROCESSED" AND UpdatedDate    BETWEEN #Form.startdate# AND #Form.enddate#) AS PROCESSED_CONNECTIONS,
(ROUND((SELECT OPEN_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "OPEN",
(ROUND((SELECT DEFERRED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DEFERRED",
(ROUND((SELECT DELIVERED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DELIVERED", (ROUND((SELECT DROPPED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "DROPPED", (ROUND((SELECT PROCESSED_CONNECTIONS / (TOTAL_CONNECTIONS))*100)) AS "PROCESSED";
 </cfquery>
```

Please let me know if the above query seems to be correct?

3) Regarding the Date Format.

As mentioned above, I'm using the mask

> mm/dd/yyyy

above , while the column(UpdatedDate) in my database uses different format

> (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS)

. Is it 
going to create any problems?

Comment: 1) You should have a link to an older topic if necessary. Better yet include any relevant information in this topic. 2) It looks like you are asking multiple questions. 3) Have you tried running your code?

Comment: 3. User CFQUERYPARAM while saving to database 2. If you use "Between" in SQL  AFAIK, it retrieves records between start and end date excluding any records from start and end date 1. No answer..

Comment: Honestly some of these questions you can answer yourself by simply running the code. Did you (because it does not sound that way)? What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Also, how can I make sure that the chart is displayed after clicking `Apply' button and not as soon as the script is run. In this case the chart must be taking the default values mentioned. Please let me know.

Comment: @Aak - You should open a separate thread about downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of questions for one thread .. but I will try and address most of them. (The first question you can answer yourself, just by trying it ;-)

As far as the query, even if it ran without error - it can be improved. I am not going to rewrite the query for you, but here are the main issues

- First, **never** use raw client values directly in SQL. Always use `cfqueryparam` to protect against sql injection. It has other benefits as well, but that one is critical in a web application.
- Second, you are passing in *date strings*. Date strings are ambiguous and can be misinterpreted, depending on the format and tool doing the parsing. It is much better use date *objects* instead. One way to do that is by using `cfqueryparam` and one of the date types: `cf_sql_date` (date only) or `cf_sql_timestamp` (date and time).
- Third, as I mentioned on [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559071/playing-around-with-date-range-in-coldfusion-8), you really need to simplify your query! That many subqueries is already unwieldy .. adding date filters to each subquery makes it downright unmanageable. I would recommend looking at ways to simplify it. [Ed's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411536/104223) offered one possibility, by reducing it to a single `JOIN` and a few function calls.

> the column (UpdatedDate) uses `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS`

Well actually that is just how your IDE *displays* it to humans. It is not really stored that way. Internally, dates are stored as big numbers. However, your query does need to account for the fact that your column stores a date *and* time.

Say you wanted to retrieve all records *dated* in June:

```
    form.startDate = "06/01/2013"
    form.endDate = "06/30/2013"
```

Conceptually, you would need a sql expression like this:

```
    WHERE column BETWEEN '06/01/2013 at midnight' AND '06/30/2013 11:59:59 PM'
```

However, constructing those date/time values is a bit klunky IMO. A simpler way to handle it is using this paradigm:

```
   WHERE column >= {startDateAtMidnight}        
   AND   column <  {dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}
```

Your actual query filter would look something like this:

```
    WHERE column >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startDate#" 
                                  cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
    AND   column <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, form.endDate)#" 
                                  cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

By adding one day to `form.endDate`, and using a `<` comparison, the resulting query is:

```
    WHERE column >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'  
    AND   column < '2013-07-01 00:00:00'
```

This will produce the exact same results as the earlier BETWEEN expression.

Comment: Could you please explain what does `dateAdd('d', 1, form.endDate)` function is doing here. I read the documentation and it says that DateAdd Adds units of time to a date but unable to understand it properly.

Comment: It just adds one (1) day. This ensures the results include all records dated any *time* on the end date. See my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

Part 0). It looks like you are doing a dateAdd() operation. Submit buttons don't need to be in a `<cfinput>`

Part 1). label on `<cfinput>` only works on Flash forms? If you are using Flash forms that should have been a part of the question

Part 2). This code is open to SQL injection attacks. Use `<cfqueryparam>`

Part 3). `<cfqueryparam>` takes care of that concern too.